# Filtering data in an auto complete text view according to the selected name

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

In my android application there is a function which can filter data with respect to the selected customer code. App has an auto complete text view. User can select a specific customer. Then system filter data according to the selected customer code. If the user does not select a customer then system should display all the customer details.

At the first time If I don't select a specific customer it displays all the customer details. Then I select a specific customer and then it displays data with respect to the selected customer. But this is happening one time. At the second time if I don't select a customer then it's not displaying all the customer details. It displays data only for the previous seleteted customer.That means at the second time if I select a specific customer the system does not change the selectedCusCode from old cusCode to new cusCode. Why it is happening?

Following is my attempt.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> cusAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, lstCustName);
        cusName.setAdapter(cusAdapter);
        cusName.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                selectedCusName = parent.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();                    

                if(selectedCusName.equals(null)){
                    selectedCusCode = "--Select--";
                } else {
                    selectedCusCode = customerMap.get(selectedCusName);

                }
            }

        });
```

Here customerMap contains all the customer codes and customer names.

After selecting a customer user should click a button then it displays data according to the selected customer.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnList:
        callArchivement();
    }
}

private void callArchivement(){
    SelectDBAdapter selectDBAdapter = SelectDBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(CustomerActivity.this);
    try {
        selectDBAdapter.openDataBase();
        orderDetails = selectDBAdapter.getOrderDetails(selectedCusCode); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        selectDBAdapter.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        selectDBAdapter.close();
    }


    CustomerTable.removeAllViews();

    loadTableLayouts();    //details are displaying in a table 

}
```

What I want to know is what's the issue with these code segments?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: are you getting right `selectedCusCode` , when you are selection any item ?

Comment: if I select a specific customer it displays data with respect to that customer.But the problem is if I select another customer it displays data with respect to previous selected customer.It is not changed into relevant customer code at the second time.

Comment: debug it line by line and get some specific reason of it like, not getting current selected customer code, or not getting right value from database, or not updating view according to data ? these are may be reason of it so be specific

Comment: if I select a specific customer it displays data with respect to that customer.But the problem is if I delete the selected customer name from the auto complete text view it displays data with respect to previous selected customer.The customer code is not changed at the second time. But if I select different customer it displays data according to that customer i.e.if I select a different customer new customer code will change into new customer code.But the problem is if I don't select a customer it will not change the customer code.

Comment: If User doesn't select a specific customer system should display all the customer details.But it's not happening.

Comment: try to set `addTextChangedListener` instead of `setOnItemClickListener`  on `cusName` and recheck this conditon `if(selectedCusName.equals(null))`

Comment: Nice to listen that its worked...